# jquery плагин для multiple select

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите плагин для реализации такого `select'a`, или статьи, или натолкните на мысль, как реализовать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://select2.github.io/examples.html#multiple

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот такой нехитрый и сложночитаемый код пишется за полтора часа :)
Все функции объяснил комментариями

```js
// Скрипт
$(function() {
  $('[role="select"]').each(function() {
    var e = this;
    // Обромляем содержимое в блок и добавляем ещё одно поле для добавления тегов
    $(e).html('<div role="field"></div><div role="list">' + $(e).html() + '</div>');
    var field = $(this).find('[role="field"]'), // Получаем блок с где будут сохраняться теги
      list = $(this).find('[role="list"]'); // Получаем блок с option
    $(e).val(''); // Создаём для элемента [role="select"] значение value
    // Проверяем, есть ли выбранные option
    if (list.find('option[selected]').length > 0) {
      // Если да, то создаём для каждого option функцию
      list.find('option[selected]').each(function() {
        var val = $(this).attr('value') || $(this).text(); // Получаем значение option из атрибута value или, если его нет, из содержимого
        // Проверяем, пустое ли поле с тегами
        if ($(e).val() == '') {
          $(e).val(val); // Если пустое, то просто добавляем значение val
        } else {
          $(e).val($(e).val() + ',' + val); // Если не пустое, то к содержимому добавляем запятую и значение option. Делаем что-то типа массива
        };
        var tag = $('<span role="tag">' + $(this).text() + ' <span role="remove">x</span></span>'); // Создаём тег
        tag.prop('index', $(this).index()).val(val); // Записываем в него индекс соответствующего option и 
        field.append(tag); // Добавляем тег в конец поля
        $(this).hide(); // Скрываем элемент option
      });
    };
    // Создаём функцию нажатия на option
    $(e).on('click', 'option', function() {
      var val = $(this).attr('value') || $(this).text(), // Получаем значение value элемента option и если его нет, то его содержимое
        valArr = $(e).val().split(','); // Создаём из значения value элемента [role="select"] массив, что бы проверить на наличие элемента
      // Проверяем, добавлено ли уже это значение в value элемента [role="select"], что бы пользователь не мог добавить копию значения
      if(valArr.indexOf(val) == -1){
        // Если значения в value элемента [role="select"] нет, то проверяем value на содержимое. Пустое ли оно
        if ($(e).val() == '') {
          // Если да, то просто добавляем val в value
          $(e).val(val);
        } else {
          // Если value не пустое, то к содержимому добавляем запятую и значение val. Создаём что-то вроде строчного массива
          $(e).val($(e).val() + ',' + val);
        };
        var tag = $('<span role="tag">' + $(this).text() + ' <span role="remove">x</span></span>'); // Создаём тег
        tag.prop('index', $(this).index()).val(val); // Записываем в тег индекс элемента option, на который нажали и его val
        field.append(tag); // Добавляем тег в конец поля
        $(this).hide(); // Прячем option
        list.hide(); // Скрываем список с option, для эффекта :)
      };
    // Создаём функцию нажатия на поле с тегами
    }).on('click', '[role="field"]', function() {
      list.toggle(); // Открываем или закрываем список с option при нажатии на поле с тегами
    // Создаём функцию удаления тега из списка при нажатии на [role="remove"]
    }).on('click', '[role="remove"]', function() {
      var optInx = $(this).parent('[role="tag"]').prop('index'), // Получаем из тега индекс соответствующего option
          val = $(this).parent('[role="tag"]').val(); // Получаем из тега value соответствующего option
      $(this).parent('[role="tag"]').remove(); // Удаляем тег
      list.find('option').eq(optInx).show(); // Ищем нужный option по индексу и показываем его
      var valArr = $(e).val().split(','); // Создаём из значений value элемента [role="select"] массив для удаления значения
      valArr.splice(valArr.indexOf(val),1); // С помощью функции indexOf ищем положение нужно value в массиве и удаляем его
      $(e).val(valArr.join(',')); // Создаём из массива строку и переписываем значение value в [role="select"]
    });
  });
  // Создаём функцию нажатия на любой элемент сайта
  $(document).click(function(e) {
    // Проверяем, нажатие было на элемент [role="field"] или нет
    if($(e.target).closest('[role="field"]').length == 0){
      // Если нет, то скрываем список option
      $('[role="list"]').hide();
    };
    
    // Проверять нужно потому, что у нас уже есть событие нажатия на [role="field"] и что бы не возникло "противоречий"
  });
});

// Проверка значение
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    console.log($('[role="select"]').val());
  });
});
```

```css
[role="select"] {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
[role="select"] > [role="field"] {
  display: block;
  -webkit-appearance: menulist;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  align-items: center;
  white-space: pre;
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 27px;
  padding: 1px;
  -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: default;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-image: initial;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-color: rgb(169, 169, 169);
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: arial;
}
[role="select"] > [role="field"] > [role="tag"] {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 1px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
[role="select"] > [role="field"] > [role="tag"] > [role="remove"] {
    display: inline-flex;
    margin-left: 3px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #cfcfcf;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
[role="select"] > [role="list"] {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: -1px 0 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: arial;
}
[role="select"] > [role="list"] > option {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
[role="select"] > [role="list"] > option:hover {
  background-color: #1b8bfa;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div role="select" name="myselect">
  <option value="Значение 1" selected>Пункт 1</option>
  <option value="Значение 2">Пункт 2</option>
  <option value="Значение 3">Пункт 3</option>
</div>
<button>Показать значение select</button>
```

Или есть пара готовых, более усовершенствованных версий:

- http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/
- https://github.com/alxlit/bootstrap-chosen
- http://krazedkrish.com/select-multiple/

Comment: SO теперь сервисом копи-паста стал что ли? ловите минус

Comment: @teran, минус за то что код написал? Справедливость на высшем уровне от "гения" кодинга

Comment: хороший ответ это не вставленный код. Что бы ответ был хорошим он должен объяснять и учить чему то а копи-пастия сплошная только плодит бездумное копирование, без какого-либо понимая что ты копируешь, что оно делает, и как оно работает. Это обычно только ухудшает ситуацию, и совершенно никак не повышает профессиональный уровень спрашивающего. Так что да, голый код это плохой ответ, за это и минус.

Comment: @teran, согласен. Но вы бы написали сами такой плагин и попробовали объяснить его написание. Хотя я сейчас попробую

Comment: вот вам ссылочка про [хорошие ответы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), а по поводу написать самому, поверьте, за более чем 10 лет программирования я много чего писал.

Comment: @teran, пока не видел не одну вашу работу

Comment: @teran, так лучше? Объяснил все функции в коде

Comment: конечно, лучше. Минус снял. Но советую почитать о том, как писать комментарии. Комментарий не должен дублировать код. То есть не надо строку вида `if(i > 0)` снабжать комментарием `если i больше нуля`, или для `while(true)` писать `бесконечный цикл`, ибо эти комментарии бессмысленны, они просто дублируют код, и могут помочь только тому, кто постигает азы программирования (хотя мб в контексте данного вопрос это и полезно). Это я про комменты к `onclick`.

Comment: Код, он как текст, его надо читать, он должен быть self-documented Или self-explained, а читабельность определяется корретным именованием переменных, классов, методов. Лучше объяснить подход в целом, прокомментировать отдельные нюансы. Ну да ладно, не будем разводить полемику на сей счет. Хочу напомнить, что минус я изначально не коду вашему поставил,а ответу. Тут плохие вопросы минусуют за то что они не содержательны, вот с ответами та же история. Так что не обижайтесь :)

Comment: @teran на мой взгляд ваша простановка минуса -- это зло, вы демотивируете давать ответы. я в таких случаях добавляю предложение расписать подробнее ответ и "мимокрокодил" дальше.

Comment: @AK я же расписал, почему минус поставил. Ибо ответ как и вопрос должен быть хорошим. Изначально тут был голый кусок кода без единого слова по сабжу. После того как появились комменты в коде я снял минус.

Comment: @teran Я всего лишь высказал вам своё частное мнение. Возможно, через пару тысяч репутации вы поменяете своё мнение, у меня были моменты, которые я понял много впоследствии, были и те, которые не изменились с момента регистрации. Вы в своём праве и убеждения у вас неплохие, я под ними тоже готов подписаться. Просто как уж совсем жестко... Программисту ещё нужны и "soft skills", общения с людьми, а не только навыки хорошо решать задачи. Будьте немного толерантнее -- вот и всё, что я хотел сказать.